# junit platform console "--classpath DIR/*" doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, code-coverage, junit5

So I have been trying to use intelliJ coverage agent "intellij-coverage-agent-1.0.735.jar" to generate a report for test coverage same as intellij's results. To execute the tests I have to use the junit5 platform console "junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.1.jar". But, this method produced the following errors:

```
$ java -javaagent:intellij-coverage-agent-1.0.735.jar=config.args -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.1.jar --scan-classpath -cp target/classes:target/test-classes/
 
Failures (1):
  JUnit Jupiter:ExampleTest:evensTest()
    MethodSource [className = 'x.y.codecoverage.example.ExampleTest', methodName = 'evensTest', methodParameterTypes = '']
    => java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/libs/lib/LibName
```

The cause of this issue, is that junit console requires libraries to execute the tests. So I used maven-dependency-plugin to generate the libs to a directory inside the project and I passed the path of that directory with an "*" to the `--classpath`/`-cp` like this:

```
$ java -javaagent:intellij-coverage-agent-1.0.735.jar=config.args -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.1.jar --scan-classpath -cp target/classes/:target/test-classes/:target/lib/*
```

But to no avail, the issue persists.

Eventually I tried to specify the name of the lib in the classpath like the following:

```
$ java -javaagent:intellij-coverage-agent-1.0.735.jar=config.args -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.1.jar --scan-classpath -cp target/classes/:target/test-classes/:target/lib/LibName.jar
```

And it worked. But now I have to pass the libs for every project and I am trying to use this inside a CI/CD pipeline for all maven projects and doing it manually or through a script sounds counter intuitive.

If you need more info please do let me know.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: So you found out that Java’s -cp option does not work with wildcards, just as described in the documentation. What is your question?